# How Can I generate a QRCode image from a String using Vala?

Tags: gtk, qr-code, gnome, vala

I want to generate a QR code image from a URL String and then show it in a GtkImage Widget.

I found the libqrencode lib but, I can't figure how to get or save the image generated.

https://valadoc.org/libqrencode/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

[According to the documentation](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/manual/structQRcode.html), "Symbol data is represented as an array contains width*width uchars. Each uchar represents a module (dot). If the less significant bit of the uchar is 1, the corresponding module is black."

With a little bit of processing you should be able to use that to create a [Gdk.Pixbuf](https://valadoc.org/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/Gdk.Pixbuf.html) (basically, convert that one bit to 3 bytes for an RGB image, then load that using Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data), or draw it using Cairo so it looks nice at any resolution.